Lunarway Shuttle: Referencing current directory from within shuttle.yaml
is there a way to somehow reference the current directory from within shuttle.yaml?
I was thinking about something like:
plan: ../shuttle-plan
vars:
main:
path: getCurrentPath

scripts:
getPath:
actions:
getCurrentPath:
- shell: pwd

but it's not working.
Thanks in advance
